# I want to run only Prettier when saving files with VSCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, formatter, prettier

I want to format with Pretter when saving a JS file, add VSCode Prettier extension and set it to `"editor.formatOnSave": true`.

The file is auto formatted for now, but ESLint AutoFix in the repository is also performed at the same time.

Firstly, I think that the extension of ESLint is bad, and setting `"eslint.autoFixOnSave": false` has no effect.

The current situation is surpassed by running `prettier --write` with an extension that allows arbitrary commands to be run when the file is saved.

However, since formatting will run with a delay than running Prettier via extension from formatOnSave.

So, I'm exploring whether it can be done without relying on extensions other than Prettier and ESLint.

The repository is here.
https://github.com/pvcresin/es

Answer (score 0):

I would keep track on the issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/380

Seems like the autoSave enters in conflict between "format" and "ESLint fix" or Prettier etc.

You can try as temporary fix what they suggest about javascript:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering
I didn't solve it, but I gave it up.